# Array class implementation in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Going to the implementation details, I see the implementation of `Array` class as

```
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
```

Implementation of IList interface reads as

```
public interface IList : ICollection, IEnumerable
```

My question is, doesn't the `Array` class automatically implement `ICollection` and `IEnumerable` the moment it implements `IList`? Why are these implemented explicitly?

Comment: Though some of the methods of `ICollection`, `IList` and `IStructuralComparable` are implemented as explicit interface implementations, which is also documented on the MSDN page for the [`Array` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx).

Comment: @Oded, I checked this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) for the explicit interface implementations. I see explicit implementations for `ICollection` interface only. `IEnumerable` doesn't have any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of Array is:

```
Array : ICloneable, IList, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
```

Take a look on this source in [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,156e066ecc4ccedf)

Maybe you took a look on MSDN which just make document clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the source!

Comment: So you mean to say that the reflector just get designed to show all the extra interfaces for readability?

Comment: @TheSilverBullet: Yes, for more readability, on MSDN and even Object Browser, you has to look on the code to know correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
interface I
{
    void M();
}

class A : I
{
    void I.M()
    {

    }
}

class B : A
{
    void I.M() // Compilation error
    {

    }
}
```

You are free to write `I i = new B()`, but you can't implement explicitly `M` in `B`. In order to do that, you need `B` to implement `I` explicitly:

```
class B : A, I
{
    void I.M() // Is ok now.
    {

    }
}
```